# Autocomplete with loading spinner using an array as data instead of Api

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angular-material

The thread showing an example of autocomplete with a loading spinner using in memory web API as a fake API : https://itnext.io/using-angular-6-material-auto-complete-with-async-data-6d89501c4b79

The thing is that i would like to implement it with an array instead of in memory web API

So in the autocomplete.service.ts file i did that for the search function:

```
search(filter: {name: string} = {name: ''}, page = 1): Observable<IUserResponse> {

  this.commune = {
  total: 4,
  results: [

    { id: 1, name: 'Windstorm' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Bombasto' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Magneta' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Tornado' },
    { id: 5, name: 'Agnosto' }
  ]
}

/** (This works with the in mem web api but i wish to use an array instead) return 
              this.http.get<IUserResponse>('/api/users') **/

return of<IUserResponse>(this.commune)
.pipe(
  tap((response: IUserResponse) => {
    response.results = response.results
      .map(user => new User(user.id, user.name))
      // Not filtering in the server since in-memory-web-api has somewhat restricted api
      .filter(user => user.name.includes(filter.name))

    return response;
  })
  );


 }
```

This is the function where the search function is used with finalize that intercepts only observables from a http requests (

```
 async ngOnInit() {

this.usersForm = this.fb.group({
  userInput: null
})

this.usersForm
  .get('userInput')
  .valueChanges
  .pipe(
    debounceTime(300),
    tap(() => { this.isLoading = true }),
    switchMap(value => this.autocompleteService.search({ name: value }, 1)
      .pipe(
        finalize(() => { this.isLoading = false }),
      )
    )
  )
  .subscribe(users => this.filteredUsers = users.results);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To use `pipe` you need an ovservable. You can transform your your array into an observable containing your data with `of` or `from` from `rxjs` library.

It works with the in memory api because an http call return an observable.

Note that you still need an asynchronous call for your loader to appear. Maybe calling `detectChanges()` can work but You should only use it as a last resort.

Here is [a basic example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wlb1jc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-auto-active-first-option-example.ts) based on the material autocomplete documentation to show you how you could simulate the loader, but it jsut add a second to the process of retrieving your data. For this I just added `delay(1000)`. Here is the code :

.ts :

```
@Component({
  selector: "autocomplete-auto-active-first-option-example",
  templateUrl: "autocomplete-auto-active-first-option-example.html",
  styleUrls: ["autocomplete-auto-active-first-option-example.css"]
})
export class AutocompleteAutoActiveFirstOptionExample implements OnInit {
  myControl = new FormControl();
  options: string[] = ["One", "Two", "Three"];
  filteredOptions: string[];
  isSearching = false;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(200),
        tap(_ => this.isSearching = true),
        map(value => this._filter(value)),
        delay(1000),
        tap(data => {
          this.isSearching = false;
          this.filteredOptions = data;
        })
      ).subscribe();
  }

  private _filter(value: string): string[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
    
    return this.options.filter(
      option => option.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0
    );
  }
}
```

.html :

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input type="text"
           placeholder="Pick one"
           aria-label="Number"
           matInput
           [formControl]="myControl"
           [matAutocomplete]="auto">
        <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete">
            <mat-option *ngIf="isSearching; else notSearching">loader here</mat-option>
            <ng-template #notSearching>
                <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions" [value]="option">
                    {{option}}
                </mat-option>
            </ng-template>
        </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Thanks, i think "finalize" is not appropriate here in my code

Comment: @dealbuquerquefrank Yes, i don't think you need finalize, but I don't really know how to use it so i'm not sure about it. However, in this case you don't need to nest a pipe

Comment: finalize does not work with a custom observable because the observable doesn't complete ! finalize only works with http angular, i have to simulate a complete with my custom obesrvable to make finalize works !

Comment: Then as I said don't use finalize, you don't need it here. But as I said before you should not be working with a custom observable here, at least you could create an asynchronous method to manage your filters, and work with it to properly display a loader isntead of faking it with 'delay'